# (Added SQL) Sequelize hasMany association with option

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize and I'm learning with the official tutorial site(http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/)
I got stuck while trying the code on the tutorial.

The code I tried was this:

```js
const City = sequelize.define('city', { countryCode: Sequelize.STRING });
const Country = sequelize.define('country', { isoCode: Sequelize.STRING });

Country.hasMany(City, {foreignKey: 'countryCode', sourceKey: 'isoCode'});
City.belongsTo(Country, {foreignKey: 'countryCode', targetKey: 'isoCode'});

sequelize.sync();
```

When I run this code, node console gives me back an error:

> "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'cities_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'countries'"

Could anybody give me what is wrong with this? I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

The code above is from **Assotiation** part of the tutorial (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)
One-to Many associations.

---

I also attach the code auto-generated by Sequelize:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  `isoCode` VARCHAR(255),
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
  ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `countryCode` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`countryCode`) REFERENCES `countries` (`isoCode`)
  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
  ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In glance it doesn't seem SQL syntax is wrong here, but anyhow this makes the error. Can anyone figure out what is wrong? Or is this a problem of Sequelize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because the example code in Sequelize tutorial has an syntax error.

If we want to make rule for a foreign key, it has to reference the primary key of the referenced table. The problem is that in the code, the foreign key `countryCode` is trying to reference the `isoCode` of `Country` model(which is `countries` table in real MySQL DB).

```
const City = sequelize.define('city', { countryCode: Sequelize.STRING });
const Country = sequelize.define('country', { isoCode: Sequelize.STRING });

Country.hasMany(City, {foreignKey: 'countryCode', sourceKey: 'isoCode'});
City.belongsTo(Country, {foreignKey: 'countryCode', targetKey: 'isoCode'});
```

The Sequelize code above will be converted into SQL statement like this below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  `isoCode` VARCHAR(255),
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
  ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `countryCode` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`countryCode`) REFERENCES `countries` (`isoCode`)
  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
  ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

To make this syntax error fixed, we have to make `isoCode` of `City` model a primary key. Let's fix the code:

```
const City = sequelize.define('city', { countryCode: Sequelize.STRING})
const Country = sequelize.define('country', {
  isoCode: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true
  }
})
// ... the rest of code followed below
```

As we fixed the model definition, the code will be working fine as we expected!

But what I wonder is... how could the *official tutorial* post this code and let the beginners just try out it without knowing that this would not work. Of course, someone would say this is not a problem of Sequelize, but rather the problem of understanding SQL. But still I think the tutorial should be fixed to avoid this kind of happening.

---

The limitation of this solution is that, there is no point of using the option `sourceKey` and `targetKey`, because even without them, Sequelize will automatically figure out the relationship and recognize what is the source key and target key among the tables.

Still I don't get the point... I think for now, I just have to not use the sourceKey and targetkey options.